# What ZPL codes could affect the start position of a QRCode

Tags: zpl

I have an app that prints out labels to a Zebra GK420t label printer. The ZPL sends some text and a QRCode. This works fine when the printer is first turned on, but there is another app that prints to it, and after the other app has printed, the position of the QRCode changes on our labels.

I don't have access to the source for the other program so I can't see what ZPL it is sending. I know it is sending some config to the printer (Print Width for example) but I can't figure out what it could be sending to change the positioning for just the QRCode.

This is the label from our app when the label printer is first turned on
[image: default printer settings]

And this is label from our app, after the other app has printed a label and changed some settings.

[image]

The QR Code moved up and to the right, but everything else stayed in the same place.

This is some example ZPL for one of our labels

```
^XA
^PW420
^LS0
^LH0,0
^CF0,40^FO20,25^FDUnknown Vendor^FS
^FO15,0^BQN,2,6^FD##hCsck00000000000779/221a1^FS
^CFR,15^FO55,220^FD3877^FS
^CFR,15^FO180,70^FDTue 07:30 Nov 10^FS
^FO180,100^FDU. Surgeon^FS
^FO180,130^FDTotal hip^FS
^FO180,160^FDsigma^FS
^FO180,190^FDHip tool^FS
^FO180,220^FD1 of 2^FS
^XZ
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

^BY (Bar Code Field Default) is the only command that can affect all barcodes. However it shouldn't affect field origin, but you may want to test this.

Your best bet is to print a config label before and after and look for the difference. Also, it's good practice to create a 'config' format and send as needed. In your case where you are sharing the printer among different applications you should send the config each time you print.

We have many Zebra printers across our manufacturing site, and we send all of the config data each time we print a label.

If you have an Ethernet enabled printer you should also be able to type the IP address into IE and view the printer config information from your web browser.

Regards,

Comment: I managed to get a copy of the ZPL the other app is sending, and they do use ^BY. I'll have to play around on a test printer to check this, the barcode height they set is the same as the vertical movement I'm seeing on the QR Code. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 3):

For some more info on Brians answer, in case anyone comes up against this. The ^BY field does affect QRCodes on the GK420t printer.

The other vendor was setting the barcode defaults

```
^BY2,2,59
```

And that was moving the QR Code down by 59. I've tested it on another model which didn't have the same issue so I think it's a bug.

Comment: Had this issue as well, on a Zebra ZT410. Using `^BY0,0,0` fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in 600 dpi Subst ^FO15,0 with ^FO15,050
015,050 is the position of qr code inside your label.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting ^LH0,0 right after ^XA. That fixed mine.